# VJS how to navigate to the next tr with enter key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to vanilla navigate to the next input cell of my table via enter key, no matter where I start from. It could be the last row, last cell, then the enter key would take me back to row 1, cell 1. Here is a simplified version of my project. `nextElementSibling` returns null (as it should) at the end of the row. Can't figure out how to move up to the parent or back and forth. Note input fields are dynamically created. The original code has several rows.

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<style>
table {
width: 100%;}

/* if the browser window is at least 800px-s wide: */
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  table {
  width: 90%;}
}

/* if the browser window is at least 1000px-s wide: */
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  table {
  width: 80%;}
}
</style>
</head>
<table id="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="1"></td>
<td id="2"></td>
<td id="3"></td>
<td id="4"></td>
<td id="5"></td>
<td id="6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="7"></td>
<td id="8"></td>
<td id="9"></td>
<td id="10"></td>
<td id="11"></td>
<td id="12"></td>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<script>
    for (i=1; i < 13 ; i++){
          var element = document.createElement("input");
          element.setAttribute("style", "width:33px;");
//           element.setAttribute("onkeydown", "matchFunc(event);"); works as well        
          var tempID = document.getElementById(i)
          tempID.addEventListener("keydown", keydownFunc)
          tempID.appendChild(element);

    }
    function keydownFunc(event) {
      var x = event.keyCode;        
      if (x == 13 | x == 9) {          
        console.log(event.target.value); 
          try{
            var nextInput = event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0];
            nextInput.focus();
          }catch (error){
            console.log(error)
          }             
//           process input
      }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Trying to help (not trying to be what you mentioned....): https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use
`nextInput = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].nextElementSibling.childNodes[0];` 
to navigate up to the parent-parent element